# Python: import a lib with a non-py extension

Tags: python, sage

I have to import library which is called `functions.sage`. How can I do it? I tried:

```
__import__('functions.sage')
```

and also this:

```
import imp
imp.load_source('fun', 'functions.sage')
```

**Edit**:

Actually I want to import [sage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagemath) lib into sage. And that lib contains sage-specific code. I tired above variants in sage interpreted. And both gave me 'no functions module' or something like this.

Comment: What errors do you see? I just tried out your second version with success.

Comment: Does `functions.sage` really contain pure Python code? If yes, why doesn't it have a `.py` extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary: in order to load a function from a `.sage` lib in `sage` - one has to parse the `.sage` file first - it will make a `.py` file - and then `import` the `.py` file.

Example:

```
import os
os.system(os.curdir + os.sep + 'functions.sage')
from functions import states
```

This way the `.sage` code got executed in sage - not in python - as it would be if one will use Sven Marnach's answer (which is absolutely right - but I stated the question in a wrong way - I forgot to mention that the code's source has to be executed in python.

Answer (score 6):

This isn't a good idea.  (This is right at the borderline between an answer and a comment, but I wanted to give examples hard to cram into a comment.)

The .sage file either contains Sage-specific syntax and behaviour or it doesn't.  If it doesn't, you can simply rename it to .py, or make a symbolic link, or whatever.  But if it does, then you're going to have to preparse it anyway before it'll work in Python.

For example, if the "functions.sage" file writes:

```
x = 2/3
```

if you load the file into sage, you get an element of QQ:

```
sage: x
2/3
sage: parent(x)
Rational Field
```

but in Python 2, you'd simply get int(0).

It might use Sage-style ranges:

```
sage: [1,3,..,11]
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]
```

or other Sage features:

```
sage: F.<x,y> = GF(2)[]
sage: F
Multivariate Polynomial Ring in x, y over Finite Field of size 2
```

and all of these are dealt with by the Sage preparser, not by Python.  Behind the scenes, it's doing this:

```
sage: preparse("F.<x,y> = GF(2)[]") 
"F = GF(Integer(2))['x, y']; (x, y,) = F._first_ngens(2)"
```

UPDATE: Apparently I didn't make the problem clear enough.

```
sage: import imp 
sage: !cat functions.sage 
x = 2/3
sage: functions = imp.new_module("functions")                         
sage: execfile("functions.sage", vars(functions))          
sage: dir(functions)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'x']
sage: functions.x
0
sage: type(functions.x)
<type 'int'>
```

One way or another, you're going to have to pass functions.sage through the preparser.

Comment: +1 Agreed. If it's a sage file, use sage to read it. If it's a Python file, give it a `.py` ending.

Comment: @DSM: indeed one should preparse the file - if it has a sage-specific code. But I'm actually wanted to import a sage lib into sage interpreter. Thank You for answer.

Comment: @user1207511: but execfile bypasses the Sage preparser.  I'll update to explain.

Comment: +2. Agreed: the code should be executed in sage not in python. I found a simple way to that. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I would really need to do this, I'd probably go with

```
functions = imp.new_module("functions")
execfile("functions.sage", vars(functions))
```

This isn't exactly equivalent to importing, since the module won't go in `sys.modules`, and it won't be looked up there if already loaded, but if you need these steps, they are easy to add.

Comment: Well - no exactly a python code: a [sage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagemath) code - is a superset of Python's. But it works! Thank You so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [execfile](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#execfile) to read the file. Not used it before myself, but looks like it reads the file contents into local scope.